# How to redirect an unauthenticated user to laravel login page with vue-router

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I'm working on a mini-shopping cart project with vue.js front end and laravel back-end. The pages are accessible to guests until they get to the checkout page, which should only be accessible by authenticated users. I am making use of `vue-router` for navigation between the urls that are accessible by guests. When a user has chosen the items he/she wants to order, they click on a button

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'checkout', params: {total: totalCost}}" class="btn btn-default">Proceed to Checkout</router-link>
```

which takes them to the authenticated checkout page if they are authenticated (I have created a controller with auth middleware to handle this). If they are not authenticated, i want to redirect them to the laravel login page so they could log in and return to the checkout page after login. I have a vue-route navigation guard to handle this:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next)=>{
    if(to.matched.some(rec => rec.meta.requiresAuth)){          
        const authUser = window.Laravel.user
        if(authUser){
            next()
        }else{
            const login = router.push('/login')
            next(login)
        }
    }
    next()
})
```

The issue is that this doesn't work as i get redirected to an empty `login` path.  Just to be sure i tried redirecting to a vue component i created in my route file like so:

```
{path: '/checkout-test', name: 'checkoutTest', props:true, component: checkoutTest, meta:{requiresAuth: true}}
```

This worked very well.Which means the issue is likely in my interception by laravel authentication. I want laravel to handle the authentication as against vue.js, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is Laravel login page static thing - rendered on server side ? I mean It's not the Vue component ?

Comment: Yes laravel login page is rendered on server side..its not a vue component

Comment: well Vue router doesn't know anything about Laravel internals, so you probably need to use `window.location.replace()` instead of router.push.

Comment: Thanks @ Belmin.Ive tried that but upon login I won't be redirected to the intended checkout url